# How To Remove a SKSpriteNode in didBeginContact

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

How do I remove a SKSpriteNode in the didBeginContact method? 
I have the node as a global variable, (node:SKSpriteNode!), and I change it's position throughout in a couple functions. However, when it is in contact with another object, I want to remove it from the screen. How should I accomplish that?

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case ColliderType.Star.rawValue | ColliderType.Cup.rawValue:
        println("")
    default:
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a global variable when you have multiple balls on screen.

if the `categoryBitMask` of ball is `bitMaskBall`, you can remove from parent the node that is in the contact object passed to `didBeginContact`

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var ball : SKNode? = nil
    // Change it to categoryBitMask of the ball sprite
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bitMaskBall &&  contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bottomBitMask { 
        ball = contact.bodyA.node
    }
    else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bitMaskBall && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bottomBitMask {
        ball = contact.bodyB.node
    }

    ball?.removeFromParent()

}
```

The conditions check if any of the bodies involved in the contact is the ball using the `categoryBitMask` of the ball. Then we extract the node inside the colliding body and finally remove it.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Let's say I have a cup collecting these balls. All of this is in 2D, therefore the cup resembles an upside down trapezoid. The base of the trapezoid (opening of the cup) is where the balls are supposed to be collected. So, 1. Is there any way where I could animate the ball into the cup. 2. How do I make it so that only when the ball is in contact with the opening of the cup it disappears, not when it is in contact with the rest of the perimeter of it. Thanks so much for your help and time!

Comment: Ok. This is a complicated question and should be a separate question really. You should ask a new question here and in split the question into less complicated parts.

Comment: Could you possible take a look at my new question?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from its parent by using `removeFromParent()` method:

```
sprite.removeFromParent()
```

Comment: When I do that, it removes the next sprite, not the one making contact.

Comment: For example, if I had a balls falling from the sky, and a ball hit the ground, it wouldn't be the ball that hit the ground that got removed. It would be the next ball falling from the sky.

Comment: @rakeshbs  I have about 3-4 balls on the screen at once. (They spawn every 0.5 seconds at different x coords).